# How do I deal with 'lib' not specified error in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Am trying to install the tidyverse in R version 4.2 and I used the command

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
```

this is what I got

```
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:\Users\MYDELL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8ElraR/repos_https%3A%2F%2Fcran.rstudio.com%2Fsrc%2Fcontrib.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:\Users\MYDELL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8ElraR\file2484306c33bf', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open the connection
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/MY DELL/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:\Users\MYDELL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8ElraR/repos_https%3A%2F%2Fcran.rstudio.com%2Fsrc%2Fcontrib.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:\Users\MYDELL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8ElraR\file248428a176cc', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open the connection
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tidyverse’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:\Users\MYDELL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8ElraR/repos_https%3A%2F%2Fcran.rstudio.com%2Fbin%2Fwindows%2Fcontrib%2F4.2.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:\Users\MYDELL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8ElraR\file2484528415b1', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2:
  cannot open the connection
```

I can see a number of errors here and am not sure how to handle any of them

Comment: `unable to access index for repository https` (to me) usually indicates network/firewall problems, make sure (1) you can browser to https://cran.rstudio.com in a web browser without problem; and (2) you have no proxy settings, either local or corporate. (Often proxy settings are not inherited by R.)